# Markdown + pandoc + beamer, how to set the aspect ratio?

Tags: beamer, pandoc, markdown

I'm using the command `pandoc -t beamer in.md -o out.pdf` to generate slides from a markdown file. It seems the default aspect ratio is 4:3. How do I set it to 16:9?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the `aspectratio` variable in the YAML metadata at the beginning of the file:

```
---
title: 'My presentation'
author:
- Author One
- Author Two
...
aspectratio: 169
---
```

Check the [man pages](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#variables-for-beamer-slides) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the class option in the header of the `.md` file:

```
---
classoption: "aspectratio=169"
---

test
```